# In VSCode, Requests throw SSLError despite verify=false

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, visual-studio-code, python-requests

Strangely, on VSCode jupyter notebook, I can use requests fine. However, on a VSCode python window, it keeps throwing the SSL error below even though I use verify=False.

The code I run:

```py
import requests
r = requests.get('https://www.webpage.com/', verify=False)
```

The error I get:

```
Exception has occurred: SSLError
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.americandragon.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /LatinIndividualHerbIndex2.html (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  File "C:\Users\breno\Documents\BBrito\code\Klaus\get_herbs.py", line 11, in <module>
    r = requests.get('https://www.americandragon.com/LatinIndividualHerbIndex2.html', verify=False)
```

Comment: You seem to have a broken Python installation where the ssl module is not working or missing.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the different **python interpreters** between `jupyter notebook` and `python file`, is that right?

It looks like there are some problems with the `SSL` model in the environment which you selected for your python file.

Can you switch to the python interpreter which has been used in the `Jupyter NoteBook` for your python file?